# Simple UITableView displaying weird data order

Tags: ios, uitableview

I create the following data on viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    food = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"Harvey's",@"McCormicks",@"Subway",nil];
    gifts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"The gift Shop",@"Lilo Gifts",@"Prezzies for All", nil];
    services = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hair Snippers",@"Laundro-mat",@"Accountants",@"Shoe fitters", nil];
    hotel = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hotel Paradiso",@"Dick & Doms B&B",@"Super Hotel",@"Castle B&B", nil];
    pubs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"The Snuggly Duckling",@"Beer's Arms",@"Merlins Beard", @"Cheers", nil];


}
```

Here are my data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 5;
}

- (NSString*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return NSLocalizedString(@"Food & Restaraunts", nil);
        case 1:
            return NSLocalizedString(@"Shopping/ Gifts", nil);
        case 2:
            return NSLocalizedString(@"Services", nil);
        case 3:
            return NSLocalizedString(@"Hotels / B&B's", nil);
        case 4:
            return NSLocalizedString(@"Pubs",nil);

        default:
            return nil;
    }



}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 3;
        case 1:
            return 3;
        case 2:
            return 4;
        case 3:
            return 4;
        case 4:
            return 4;
        //default:
        //  return 1;

    }



}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //mine  

        switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        [[ cell textLabel]
         setText:[food objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        break;
    case 1:
        [[ cell textLabel]
         setText:[gifts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        break;
    case 2:
        [[ cell textLabel]
        setText:[services objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        break;
    case 3:
        [[ cell textLabel]
        setText:[hotel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        break;
    case 4:
        [[ cell textLabel]
        setText:[pubs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        break;

    } 

    return cell;
}

}
```

What its actually doing is displaying the first 10 lines correctly then repeating the list again, if I add more lines to the first couple of sections it repeats earlier up the table.. I've cleared the cache etc but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you set contents of your reusable cells only once.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];}
//mine  

    switch (indexPath.section) {
case 0:
    [[ cell textLabel]
     setText:[food objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    break;
case 1:
    [[ cell textLabel]
     setText:[gifts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    break;
case 2:
    [[ cell textLabel]
    setText:[services objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    break;
case 3:
    [[ cell textLabel]
    setText:[hotel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    break;
case 4:
    [[ cell textLabel]
    setText:[pubs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    break;



return cell;}
```

I am not good at post formatting. You should set content of your cell after taking it from "reuse stack".

Comment: After taking cell with reuse identifier and checking if it is `nil`, you should only alloc and init your cell and make some settings that will not change regardless of content. After that you should add you content to cell. In your case you just set text of `textLabel`. Main point is that you should do it only after having cell either with reuse identifier or by creating new one. Look at apple's [Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10)

Comment: I'm still trying to get my head around this, but why does it only do the first 10? I cant work out where this number comes from..

Comment: I think that is number of visible rows on screen. Table View creates 10 cell's and caches them. All other cells are taken from cache and thair content is not chaged.

Comment: worked it out, just needed to move the brace bracket up and then remove from the end.